# Why sys.path doesn't contain cwd()?

Tags: python, linux, shell, emacs

I use python3 with emacs (editor and shell) under Linux OS. Why the cwd is not in the sys.path ?? How can we put it, for all sessions !!
I Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do **not** want to add `cwd()` to the `sys.path`. *Always* adding `cwd()` would be a *terrible idea* as you can no longer control what files are available for import.

Python adds the *directory of the script being executed* instead.

E.g. when you run:

```
python.exe path/to/script.py
```

then `path/to` is automatically added to the `sys.path`.

Only if you run a script from the current directory is `''` added to the start of the path, meaning the current working directory is searched for imports. E.g. when you run `python.exe localfile.py` then Python does add the current working directory, in the assumption you wont't change the current working directory while importing.

See [*Interface options*](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#interface-options) in the *Command line and environment* documentation:

> If the script name refers directly to a Python file, the directory containing that file is added to the start of `sys.path`, and the file is executed as the `__main__` module.

and the [`sys.path` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path):

> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, `path[0]`, is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter. If the script directory is not available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the script is read from standard input), `path[0]` is the empty string, which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first. Notice that the script directory is inserted before the entries inserted as a result of `PYTHONPATH`.

You can always add the current working directory to `sys.path` explicitly:

```
import sys

if sys.path[0] != '':
    sys.path.insert(0, '')
```

Be careful, any python file or package in that working directory with a name matching a module you are already using in your code will mask that module, easily leading to breakage.

Comment: My problem exists only with emacs. With emacs sys.path[0]='/usr/share/emacs/23.3/etc'. The command from file import * doesn't work. Python can't see the module. When I use Terminal sys.path[0]='' or with IDLE sys.path[0]='/home/me' and module in my cwd are seen

Comment: Ah, that may well be a problem with *just Emacs*, not with Python in general.

Answer (score 1):

[`sys.path` isn't the System Path, it's the path that `python` checks when looking for modules (when you execute `import` statements, for example).](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)

To change it permanently, change the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: This doesn't give you the option to add the *current working directory* to `sys.path` however, as that depends on the current shell session.

Comment: This is how you change what `sys.path` evaluates to, in case they still want to add `cwd` to it.

Comment: But the current working directory is *dynamic*; one `cd` call is all it takes to invalidate `PYTHONPATH` as it will no longer include the *current working directory* anymore.

Comment: I know it's dynamic, I don't know how they'd do it. I'm just telling them how to change it permanently, however they want to go about it.

Comment: Setting `PYTHONPATH` permanently is almost always a bad idea, for the reasons Martijn cites.  Python provides other, better options, like modifying `sys.path`, using `.pth` files, `virtualenv`s, or just installing something.  Best to find out what the OP is really trying to do first.

Comment: I agree that it's bad, but it's what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable.
This prepends locations to the default module search path.
The [docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) say that, when running a script from the command line,
the first item in `sys.path` will be the path to the script.
The docs say that `sys.path` is then
“initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default.”
For example, if `PYTHONPATH` is empty (PowerShell: `$env:PYTHONPATH = ""`),
only the installation-dependent default is added.
**However**, if `PYTHONPATH` starts with an empty string,
then the current working directory (that the script is run from) is added to `PYTHONPATH`.
(Even just an initial separator will add this—for example a semicolon in PowerShell: `$env:PYTHONPATH = ";"`.)
This is not always the desired behavior,
so you may wish to hesitate before making permanent changes in your `PYTHONPATH`.